# Php7 Upgrade issues with << bitwise operators

Tags: php

I had following code working in php 5.6 but after php7 upgrade, it stops working, do you have any idea how to do this on PHP 7.0 ?

```
public function getChecksParam($array) {
    $v = 0;
    foreach ( $array as $param ) {
        $v |= 1 << $param - 1;
    }
    return $v;
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on "stops working" / what it's supposed to do / how and which concrete issue you identified there?

Comment: its called left shit operator, dev should be familier with it.

Comment: Are you sure it's called a *left shit operator*?? I have my doubts...

Comment: sorry "Bitwise Operators"

Comment: i actually fixed it using if($param > 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was causing after the upgrade PHP seems to have fixed a bug that when it defaults to 0 on invalid bitwise-shift

so i have to do some validations before doing the bitwise shift see below for the correct code that working.

```
public function getChecksParam($array) {
    $v = 0;
    foreach ( $array as $param ) {
         if($param > 0 )
           $v |= 1 << $param - 1;
         else
           $v = 0;   
    }
    return $v;
}
```